# Error with LoadingOption when I want set new loadingController

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi I'm new on Ionic and I have this error when I want create new loadingScreen.

```
Argument of type '{ content: string; }' is not assignable to parameter 
of type 'LoadingOptions'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'content' does not exist in type 'LoadingOptions'.
```

I see [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.1/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) and I think the syntax is good.

```
   const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
        content: 'Please wait...',
    });
    await loading.present();
```

Comment: just try let loading instead of const loading

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like their docs are outdated, here is the interface definition in their code:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/loading/loading-interface.ts

```
export interface LoadingOptions {
  spinner?: SpinnerTypes | null;
  message?: string;
  cssClass?: string | string[];
  showBackdrop?: boolean;
  duration?: number;
  translucent?: boolean;
  animated?: boolean;

  mode?: Mode;
  keyboardClose?: boolean;
  id?: string;

  enterAnimation?: AnimationBuilder;
  leaveAnimation?: AnimationBuilder;
}
```

As you can see, there is no `content` anymore, it has been renamed to `message`.

Comment: Thanks, I've been migrating my app from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4 and this was the case everywhere I used the LoadingController, had to update everything.